# WebAuthn with Windows Hello: PIN prompt missing when allowCredentials specified, only device options shown

Tags: javascript, security, webauthn, windows-hello

I'm working on integrating WebAuthn into my web application and encountering an issue specifically with Windows Hello and the handling of `allowCredentials`. When I don't specify `allowCredentials`in the `publicKeyCredentialRequestOptions`, I get a prompt allowing me to choose from available credentials, and upon selection, I'm then asked to enter the PIN for the selected credential. This flow works as expected.

However, my goal is to streamline the process by pre-selecting the credential using `allowCredentials`, thus skipping the credential selection step. When I do specify `allowCredentials`with the correct credential ID, the expected PIN prompt does not appear. Instead, I'm only presented with two options: "iPhone, iPad, or Android device" and "Security Key".

Here's the code snippet for context:

```
const publicKeyCredentialRequestOptions = {
    challenge: serverChallenge,
    rpId: window.location.hostname,
    userVerification: 'required',
    allowCredentials: [
        {
            type: "public-key",
            id: allowCredentials[0].id,
        }
    ],
};

const credential = await navigator.credentials.get({
    publicKey: publicKeyCredentialRequestOptions
});
```

The `allowCredentials[0].id` is verified to be correct. The issue is that specifying `allowCredentials` emphasized textseems to bypass the PIN entry step for Windows Hello, directly prompting for an alternate authentication method instead.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have insights on why the PIN prompt is bypassed in this case? Any advice on how to ensure the PIN prompt appears when `allowCredentials` is used would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming a bit here but I would guess that the ID you send in is actually not in the format expected. The `allowCredential` expects a [PublicKeyCredentialDescriptor](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#dictionary-credential-descriptor) which eexpects that the ID is sent in as a `BufferSource`. However the [PublicKeyCredential](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#iface-pkcredential) response object from the creation is not of the same type. For the `PublicKeyCredential` the `id` is a `base64url` encoded string of the ID and not an actual `BufferSource`.

This would result in WebAuthn asking all platform authenticators first, and Windows Hello is a Platform Authenticcator, and they would all respond that they don't know said credential which would prompt you to use cross-platform authenticators, or as you refer to it as alternate authenticators.

As I said, I am assuming a bit, but I assume the `allowCredentials[0].id` is a reference to a `PublicKeyCredential` in which case swapping to `allowCredentials[0].rawId` would probably fix the issue.

If it is not a `PublicKeyCredential` you'd need to convert your id to a BufferSource. As said earlier I assume it is a base64 encoded string so something like `new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(allowCredentials[0].id, 'base64'))` might solve it. But this all depends a bit that my assumptions are correct.